# How do i delete rows with all values as 0 ignoring the nth cell?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I know how to delete rows in a dataframe with all values as 0. But I cannot find the solution if i want to ignore nth (first in the below example) cell while checking that condition.

IN:

```
   0  title1  title2 title3
cat1  0        0       1
cat2  1        0       0
cat3  1        0       1
```

OUT:

```
   0  title1  title2 title3
cat1  0        0       1
cat3  1        0       1
```

I want to remove cat2 row even the first cell is non zero.

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select all columns without first by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html), check if not equal `0` by [`DataFrame.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ne.html) with [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) for test if at least one `True`s per rows:

```
df = df[df.iloc[:, 1:].ne(0).any(axis=1)]
print (df)
      title1  title2  title3
cat1       0       0       1
cat3       1       0       1
```

**Details**:

```
print (df.iloc[:, 1:])
      title2  title3
cat1       0       1
cat2       0       0
cat3       0       1
```

Or if want ignore `nth` column is possible `drop` this column:

```
#python count from 0, so for first column is used 0
i = 0
df = df[df.drop(df.columns[i], axis=1).ne(0).any(axis=1)]
print (df)
      title1  title2  title3
cat1       0       0       1
cat3       1       0       1
```

**Details**:

```
i = 0
print (df.columns[i])
title1

print (df.drop(df.columns[i], axis=1))
      title2  title3
cat1       0       1
cat2       0       0
cat3       0       1
```

Comment: can someone (#jezrael) explain the second method. I don't see any comparison with 0

Comment: you dropped the first column. but where did you compare the rest of the dataframe for values eq or nq to 0 ?

Comment: @zealvault - Sorry, both solutions use `any`.